# handshake error on trying to connect to to node server

Tags: django, node.js, handshake, socket.io

I have followed some tutorials and built a chat application using nodejs,socket io and django which works fine locally in ubuntu server running in virtual machine. But, when i try to run this in my live site,hosted on webfaction, i see a 'handshake error'. I have installed nodejs using this tutorial -- http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/how-to-install-node-js-on-webfaction/

client:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var socket = io.connect('http://node.username.webfactional.com');
socket.on('connect',function(){
console.log('connect'); });});
```

server:

```
var http = require('http'); 
var server = http.createServer().listen(30699,'127.0.0.1'); 
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

i get this error in the browser console on trying to connect:

GET http://node.username.webfactional.com/socket.io/1/?t=1378464435111 500 (Internal Server Error)
and a 'handshake error' error in node console. 
Any suggestions could be very helpful to me.Thank  you.

Comment: Are you sure the port 30699 is open? Are you behind a firewall or proxy?

Comment: @KurtPattyn Yes,the port is open.I figured out i get the handshake error because i cannot share cookie set by django with the node server and also in the 'authorization' function, i am checking for data.headers.cookie to authorize the client.There it fails because there is no cookie and data.headers.cookie returns undefined.I have resolved this issue by just removing the need for cookie to authorize the client. Thanks for responding.